How does one measure the fall in performance of Object Detection algorithms with degraded training images?
I'm supposed to be working on a project that involves studying of the effect on Object Detection algorithms with different kinds of training images. We(team) are supposed to measure the difference in performance of the Object Detection Model each and every time the dataset changes, especially when quality of images is at question.
We're supposed to come up with a metric that allows us to measure this change in performance. I'm told that mean average precision(mAP) and IoU might not be the best ways to make inference and instead go for something else that is fundamental to the Object Detection itself. It'd be great and if you'd suggest something out of this. I began with studying overfitting in Object Detection to get some insights. I can't get anywhere.

Consider the loss evaluated on a test set. Typically your train loss function will be differentiable while precision etc is not

Precision has the exact same problems as accuracy, so don't use mAP. I don't know what IoU is. Your case looks straightforward: pick a good evaluation metric appropriate for your use case, and measure the reduction in this metric between the original and the degraded dataset, on a holdout set (you may want to bootstrap). So I don't quite see what your question is. Is it about choosing a useful metric? If so, it would make sense to give many more details as to what you are doing: what are your images, why are you detecting, and so forth.
